# Struggling with controlling state in modal react-native - data not refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building a basic nutrition app that shows user's info regarding items they searched. 
However, when my user selects an item from the flat list, I have a modal component that pops up and shows more info regarding the item. However, when I press back on my modal and select a new item on the FlatList, the data is remaining the same from the first item I pressed :(

export default class Tracker extends React.Component {
     static navigationOptions = {
      title: "Tracker",
     };

```
//storing results from the api into this local state
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
     this.state = {
     isLoading: true,
     dataSource: null,
     show: false,
   };
 }
`
 fetchData = (item) => {
console.log(item);

fetch(
  `https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/parser? 
ingr=${item}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`
  )
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);
    //   console.log(responseJson.hints[1].food.nutrients);
    this.setState({
      // passing in all the hints info into itemArray, which contains all the info regarding 
 the items
      itemArray: responseJson.hints,


    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
 // dimisses keyboard if they press the button on the screen
 Keyboard.dismiss();
 };

<Button
      title="Search"
      onPress={() => this.fetchData(this.state.item)}
    />``
    <View style={styles.ViewFilterContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.ViewFilterContainer}>
        <View style={styles.filterButtonView}>
          <Text style={styles.filterText}> Filter </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.paddingForResultsContainer}>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.resultsBackground}
        data={this.state.itemArray}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.setState({ 
              show: true 


            })} //() => navigate("foodInfo")
          >
            <View style={styles.resultsContainer}>
              <View style={styles.textView}>
                <Text style={styles.resultsText}>
                  {item.food.label}
                  {item.food.brand}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.nutritionResultsText}>
                <Text style={styles.resultsTextSubInfo}>
                  F: {Math.round(item.food.nutrients.FAT)}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.resultsTextSubInfo}>
                  C: {Math.round(item.food.nutrients.CHOCDF)}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.resultsTextSubInfo}>
                  P: {Math.round(item.food.nutrients.PROCNT)}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.resultsTextSubInfo}>
                  K/Cal: {Math.round(item.food.nutrients.ENERC_KCAL)}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <Modal transparent={true} visible={this.state.show}>
              <View style={styles.modalView}>
                <View>
                  <Text>{item.food.brand}</Text> 
                </View>
                <Button title="Back" onPress={() => this.setState({show:false})}/> 
              </View>
            </Modal>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
```

Comment: you have a modal component for each flatlist item, but all of these modals share the same flag to show or hide. the flag is on the component's state. so it seems like you're actually showing ALL the modals at once and only one of them will actually be visible. you need to have some way to only show the modal for the particular item chosen.

Comment: another approach that is probably better is only have one modal outside the list, store the chosen item's data in state, have the modal pull that data from state. you only need 1 modal actually.